# Same Database Different Hosting Strange Charset Results

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

i have utf8 database and tables on server1. Files saved in utf8 and there are html, php and htaccess settings to set charset to utf8. Characters looks ok on server1.

i have moved all files (not database) to server2. But the data fetched by php's function mysql_query have charset problems.

i have already tried set names, collation etc. mysql queries. It looks like different server configuration. It is a simple hosting account.

Comment: `CHARACTER SET` in table?  `<meta...>` on web page?  You moved the "files"; but you are still accessing the same database?

Comment: @RickJames utf8 used in tables and meta charset is utf8. Yes i moved files to server2 and accessing the same database.

Comment: "charset problems" -- errors?  garbage output?  mojibake?  missing text?  What?

Comment: @RickJames When i fetch data from database turkish characters doesnt show right. I see it as ÅŸ, Ä±, ÄŸ, Ã¼, Ã¶, Ã§  There is no problem with the text wrote in html document. Only the ones fetched from database.

Comment: Search for "Mojibake"; it is a common problem.